# Pull data from Excel table row based on selection using Javascript API

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript

I have a table in my spreadsheet, and using `onSelectionChanged` for this table, I want to pull the data from the rows in the table that I have selected, and display it on the side within my plugin.

eg. If I select a single cell, in a single row, then I want the data from the entire *table* row that I've selected. If I do a multi select (ie. data from three rows) then I want the data from all three rows.

The part I'm struggling with is actually determine *which* row has been selected.

I could use something like this:

```
var rowRange = expensesTable.rows.getItemAt(1).load("values");
```

However, based on the selection address I don't know which rows have actually been selected in terms of an index into the table, I just know the selected addresses.

What I have so far looks like this, however I want to change this approach based on any suggestions here. In this code I'm basically trying to construct the ranges for the rows that are selected, and from there I could pull the data.

```js
async function tableSelectionChangeListener(event) {
    return await Excel.run(async (context) => {

        if(!event.isInsideTable)
            return;

        let table = context.workbook.tables.getItem(event.tableId);
        let headerRange = table.getHeaderRowRange().load("values,address")
        let bodyRange = table.getDataBodyRange()
        // Make sure we don't include the header in the selection of data
        let usableRange = bodyRange.getIntersection(event.address).load("address");        
        await context.sync();

        // Header ex:  "address": "concepts!A4:R4",
        // Body ex:    "address": "concepts!A5:R15",

        // The ranges for the rows that we'll use
        let ranges = [];

        let t = headerRange.address.split('!');
        // Extract the A4:R4 part
        let hdrRng = (t.length == 1) ? t[0] : t[1];

        // Just grab the column letters, fails with something like AA
        let startIndexColumn = hdrRng.split(":")[0][0];
        let endIndexColumn = hdrRng.split(":")[1][0];

        t = usableRange.address.split('!');
        let useRng = (t.length == 1) ? t[0] : t[1];


        let s = useRng.split(":")
        _.forEach(s, (val) => {
            con.log("val:" + val)
            // Essentially take header column letters and replace the row selection with the rows selected
            ranges.push(startIndexColumn + val.slice(1) + ":" + endIndexColumn + val.slice(1))
        })

        con.log(ranges)

        return context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following solution.

To get the index, one can just take the selected cell row and subtract the header row to get the index. If the selection is multiple rows, do it again for the end of the selection and then just loop for all indicies in between. The following is what I'm using to pull the data:

```js
async function tableSelectionChangeListener(event) {
    return await Excel.run(async (context) => {

        if (!event.isInsideTable)
            return [];

        let table = context.workbook.tables.getItem(event.tableId);
        let headerRange = table.getHeaderRowRange().load("values,address")
        let bodyRange = table.getDataBodyRange()
        // Make sure we don't include the header in the selection of data
        let usableRange = bodyRange.getIntersection(event.address).load("address");
        await context.sync();

        // The range is probably of the form `sheetName!A4:R4`. So we separate on the ! 
        let hdrAdd = headerRange.address.split('!');
        let hdrRng = (hdrAdd.length == 1) ? hdrAdd[0] : hdrAdd[1];
        let useAdd = usableRange.address.split('!');
        let useRng = (useAdd.length == 1) ? useAdd[0] : useAdd[1];

        // Then we need to split on the :
        let startIndex: number = getRow(useRng.split(":")[0]) - getRow(hdrRng.split(":")[0]) - 1
        let endIndex: number = startIndex;

        if (useRng.split(":").length > 1)
            endIndex = getRow(useRng.split(":")[1]) - getRow(hdrRng.split(":")[0]) - 1

        let tableRows = [];
        for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            var row = table.rows.getItemAt(i).load("values");
            tableRows.push(row);
        }

        return context.sync(tableRows);
    }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
}

/*
    Input: A4 or AA99, etc.
    Output: 4 or 99, etc.
*/
export function getRow(address: string): number | null {
    var regexStr = address.match(/[0-9]+/gi);
    if (Array.isArray(regexStr) && regexStr.length)
        return parseInt(regexStr[0]);
    return null;
}

/*
    Input: A4 or AA99, etc.
    Output: A or AA, etc.
*/
export function getColumn(address: string): string | null {
    var regexStr = address.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/gi);
    if (Array.isArray(regexStr) && regexStr.length)
        return regexStr[0];
    return null;
}
```